# Two legends for polar ggplot (with one customized)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my data:

```
data <- structure(list(Indicator = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Causality", 
"Climatechangeriskperceptions", "Currentadaptationoptions", "Fishingasalivelihoodactivity", 
"Governance", "Roleofshadowstateactors"), class = "factor"), 
    Village = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L), .Label = c("Andra", "lahapau", "Pelipowai", "Ponam", 
    "Tulu"), class = "factor"), Variables = structure(c(13L, 
    3L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 17L, 6L, 14L, 
    9L, 4L, 7L, 13L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
    15L, 17L, 6L, 14L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 13L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 
    5L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 17L, 6L, 14L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 13L, 3L, 10L, 
    11L, 12L, 16L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 17L, 6L, 14L, 9L, 4L, 
    7L, 13L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 17L, 
    6L, 14L, 9L, 4L, 7L), .Label = c("alternativelivelihood", 
    "anyactorsinvolvedinsustainability", "Attributionfactors", 
    "discusswithelectedleaders", "Effortsdirectedtoreducerisks", 
    "fishercommunityinfluence", "Infrastructureeffectiveness", 
    "multiplicityofactors", "Occupationforchildren", "Reversibility", 
    "Riskasamajorconsideration", "Riskbeingaddressed", "Statusoffisheries", 
    "Timefishing", "Whatwasdone", "Whoisatrisk", "whowasinvolved?"
    ), class = "factor"), legend.var = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
    17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
    14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
    "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q"), class = "factor"), 
    score = c(1, 0.97, 1, 0.76, 0.794, 1, 0.71, 0.9, 0.5, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0.49, 0.72, 1, 0.7, 1, 1, 0, 0.67, 0.5, 1, 0.2, 
    1, 1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 0.67, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 1, 0, 0.46, 
    0.56, 0.375, 1, 0.13, 0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 1, 1, 
    0.7, 0.8, 1, 0.86, 0.69, 0.51, 0.429, 1, 0.44, 0.3, 0.5, 
    0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.4, 0.79, 0.8, 1, 1, 0.82, 0.85, 0.25, 
    0.226, 1, 0.18, 0.1, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.48, 0.16, 0.4, 
    0.8)), .Names = c("Indicator", "Village", "Variables", "legend.var", 
"score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -85L))
```

I have made polar plots as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = legend.var, y = score, fill = Indicator), color='black') + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, alpha=0.5, stat="identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous() + 
  coord_polar()  + 
  theme( axis.ticks = element_blank()) + 
  facet_wrap(~Village, nrow=2, ncol=3) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title.hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

As you can see in the data, column `legend.var` is grouped by the column `indicator`. I would like to insert a table or a second legend which associates each of the indicator with the `legend.var` and `variables` column. Ideally if this is inserted as a second legend, the unique items comprised in `legend.var` column would have the same fill color as the corresponding indicator. The fill legend is based on the column `indicator`. The inserted table/extra legend would comprise columns `legend.var` with a unique alphabet and column `variables` with the meaning of the respective alphabet. These can then have the same fill color as the corresponding `indicator`. I hope this is clear.

Comment: I've edited your code to run without warnings with the current version of ggplot2. However, I do not understand your goal. Can you provide a mock-up?

Comment: @Roland I think what OP wants is to provide a lookup table for the letters. He plots letters on the x-axis of the bar plot because the names are too long. Now he wants a table that has the letter and the full name as provided in `Variables`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using a `gtable`:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = legend.var, y = score, fill = Indicator), color='black') + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, alpha=0.5, stat="identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous() + 
  coord_polar()  + 
  theme( axis.ticks = element_blank()) + 
  facet_wrap(~Village, nrow=2, ncol=3) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title.hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.position=c(0.85,0.25))

#create table
library(gridExtra)
tab <- tableGrob(unique(data[, c("legend.var", "Variables")]), 
                 show.rownames=FALSE, gpar.coretext=gpar(fontsize=10), 
                 gpar.coltext=gpar(fontsize=10, fontface='bold'),
                 gpar.corefill = gpar(fill = "grey90", col = "white"),
                 gpar.colfill = gpar(fill = "grey80", col = "white"))

#arrange grobs
library(gtable)
a <- gtable(unit(c(0.7, 0.3) ,c("npc")), unit(1, "npc"))
a <- gtable_add_grob(a, ggplotGrob(p),1,1)
a <- gtable_add_grob(a, tab,1,2)

#plot
grid.draw(a)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For a start, you may try something like this. You need to adjust arrangement and layout according to your own preferences.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

gg <- ggplot(data, aes(x = legend.var, y = score, fill = Indicator), color='black') + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, alpha=0.5, stat="identity") + 
  coord_polar()  + 
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) + 
  facet_wrap(~Village, nrow=2, ncol = 3) 

# create a table that translates legend.var to Variables 
tbl <- unique(data[ , c("legend.var", "Variables")])

# create a table grob 
tt <- tableGrob(d = tbl,
                col.just = "left",
                gpar.coretext = gpar(col = "black", cex = 0.5),
                gpar.coltext = gpar(col = "black", cex = 0.5, fontface = "bold"),
                gpar.rowtext = gpar(col = "black", cex = 0.5, fontface = "italic"))

# arrange plot and table grob
grid.arrange(gg, tt, ncol = 2)
```

**update with a quick and dirty ggplot-only alternative**

```
# create labels
labs <- with(tbl, paste(legend.var, Variables))

gg <- ggplot(data, aes(x = legend.var, y = score, fill = Indicator, col = Variables)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, alpha = 0.5, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar()  + 
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Village, nrow = 2, ncol = 3) +
  scale_color_grey(labels = labs, start = 0.8, end = 0.9)

gg
```

[image]

Comment: This works... but is there any 'canonical' `ggplot` way of doing this? Is there any way to get `scale_x_discrete` to have a "guide" which you could give alternate labels?

Comment: @nograpes, good point! I bet there is a ggplot-only way. I was thinking along that route but got stuck...

Comment: @nograpes I don't think so. And I'm not sure I can follow the concept of a guide for `scale_x_discrete`.

Comment: @Roland I might make my own question about this. But, briefly, in the same way that a guide for the `fill` aesthetic is a table of `fill` colours and an appropriate label, a guide for the `x` aesthetic would be a table of `x` labels and an appropriate new label.

Comment: much appreciated folks..exactly what @nograpes stated-a look-up table is what i am after. solution does work (without warnings),the layout however isn't great. Also the table has numbering and title. I am a novice in this, but what if you create a second legend comprising concatenated columns of the look-up table.. is this possible at all?

Comment: @nograpes, added a first step towards ggplot-only alternative. I am not very familiar with the options in `guides` and `guide_colourbar`, but I suspect it should be possible (it's R/ggplot!) to make it look nicer.

Comment: @Henrik Very nice update, this is along the lines of what I was thinking. The only problem I can see is that you do this by 'hijacking' the `colour` aesthetic (if you wanted to use this aesthetic in your plot, you wouldn't be able to now). What you really want in place of those grey boxes is just the letters. I think I will make this a new question.

Comment: @nograpes, yes it was a desperate 'hijacking' of an available `aes`. I was planning to add a new `geom`, with `aes` based on the look-up table, but where the `geom` plotted is 'invisible'. I don't know if it is possible. `geom_blank` of course doesn't add a legend?

Comment: great stuff..if at all possible and better still..for the grey boxes in the dummy legend to be assigned the color of the main legend items..since items in the look-up table are grouped by the legend items/column 'indicator'

Comment: You have several 'Indicator' per 'Variables', so which 'Indicator' colour would you choose?...

Comment: answer for Henrik..each 'indicator' has a color on the legend..in the data table, each 'indicator' is associated with 2-4 variables. Indicator is a broader grouping where each indicator comprises a few variables

Comment: sure..happy to explore different possible solutions though