# Rotation of labels to follow x-axis in ggplot2, polar projection?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, polar-coordinates

How might the angle of x-axis labels follow the same angle as the outer x-axis using the coor_polar projection in ggplot? This is similar to [rotate x-axis text in ggplot2 when using coord_polar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830022/rotate-x-axis-text-in-ggplot2-when-using-coord-polar), but I don't understand the math well enough to adapt it. I found a trial-and-error solution below that sort of works, where `angle = c(c(1:3)*c(-14,-22.3,-22),-90,c(3:1)*c(22,22.3,14),c(1:3)*c(-14,-22.3,-22),90,c(3:1)*c(22,22.3,14))`. It would also be okay for the x-axis labels to rotate in the same direction all the way around. If all else fails, I might give up on rotating the labels and just add a second legend, as in [Two legends for polar ggplot (with one customized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929052/two-legends-for-polar-ggplot-with-one-customized). Thanks for the help!

```
require(ggplot2)    
df.test <- data.frame(Names=c("name01", "name02", "name03", "name04", "name05", "name06",    "name07", "name08", "name09", "name10", "name11", "name12", "name13", "name14"),Values=rep(1,24))
p <- ggplot(df.test, aes(Names, fill=Values))
p + coord_polar(theta="x", direction=1) +
geom_bar(stat="bin", colour="gray", alpha=.7) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = c(c(1:3)*c(-14,-22.3,-22),-90,c(3:1)*c(22,22.3,14),c(1:3)*c(-14,-22.3,-22),90,c(3:1)*c(22,22.3,14))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear what your goal is but see if this answers the question:

```
+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 
            360/(2*pi)*rev( seq( pi/14, 2*pi-pi/14, len=14))))
```

That would make the names "tangential" to the splits. If you wanted them "perpendicular" (as in the illustration in the linked answer) you just add pi/2 radians to the angle. (Didn't we all take geometry in high school?)

```
+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 
            360/(2*pi)*rev( pi/2 + seq( pi/14, 2*pi-pi/14, len=14))))
```

(BTW: The data argument that you specified had an error. I changed "24" to "14".)

Let me know if the first 7 labels look right, but you want the ones on the LHS of the figure flipped.
[image]

So you want the bottom 6 rotated by pi radians (=pi*360/2*pi degrees):

```
+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 360/(2*pi)*rev( 
                                             seq(pi/14,2*pi-pi/14, len=14))+
  360/(2*pi)*c( rep(0, 4),rep(pi,6), rep(0,4)) )) 
                # the rotation "back" of the lower items
```

(I really do not understand the decision to use degrees rather than radians.)

Comment: thanks for these. Yes, I was referring to the tangential solution you provided, with the lower 5 labels flipped to be more readable. Sorry for my mathematical ignorance, I was more into literature than math in high school. The edit you made is fine.The "error" was just a relic of the plot I was working from before, and doesn't really matter; I just wanted to fill each column equally to make it less confusing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example how the solution of @42- could be implemented. Would have been useful for me.

```
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)

ax <- length(unique(mtcars$gear))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = gear, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_polar() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      angle = 360/(2*pi)*rev(seq(pi/ax,2*pi-pi/ax, len=ax)) + 360/(2*pi)*c(rep(0, round(ax/3)),rep(pi,ax-2*round(ax/3)), rep(0,round(ax/3)))
    )
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(
    breaks = levels(mtcars$cyl),
    limits = c(" ", levels(mtcars$cyl))
  )
```